# Why are all the letters of the alphabet converted to Z?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to come up with a code that will flip the alphabet backwards. Also known as the Atbash cipher. Basically, replace A with Z. B with Y. And so forth.

this is what I have so far. I used an alert to check what the cipherAlphabet is after the for loop and it's showing only half of the alphabet (until n). I am not sure where I went wrong.

```
var plainAlphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var cipherAlphabet = '';

for(var i = 0; i < plainAlphabet.length/2; i++){
    var letter = plainAlphabet.charAt(i);
    var n = 1;
    var newletter = plainAlphabet.charAt(plainAlphabet.length - n);
    cipherAlphabet+=newletter;
n = n + 1;
```

}

alert(cipherAlphabet);

}

Comment: `var n = 1` is inside the body of the loop, so `n` gets set to `1` every time.

Comment: It's also 2020, so try and use `let` in preference to `var`. It helps catch mistakes and scopes things better.

Comment: @tadman More preferably, `const`, when the variable isn't going to be reassigned

Comment: @CertainPerformance Was advocating baby steps, but you're right.

Comment: I put var n = 1 outside the loop but it is only giving me the alphabet until n. i tried removing the plainAlphabet.length/2 but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @user12788973: Please show that updated code.

Answer (score 3):

`plainAlphabet.length - n` never changes because `n = 1` each iteration.

So, `newletter` is always the same.

Answer (score 0):

The `letter` contains the letter you need to replace with its twin, but you never use that variable. To find the associated character, you might check the index of the character using character codes (65 - 90, inclusive), then invert it (so 65 turns into 90, 90 turns into 65, etc):

```js
var plainAlphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var cipherAlphabet = '';

for (const char of plainAlphabet) {
  const code = char.charCodeAt();
  const newCode = 90 - (code - 65);
  cipherAlphabet += String.fromCharCode(newCode);
}

console.log(cipherAlphabet);
```

Comment: I think the goal of the loop is just to create a reversed alphabet, with the actual translation being the next step once this works.